# kubernetes keeps on pulling old image, even with imagePullPolicy set to Always

Tags: kubernetes

I have an image on docker hub that I using in a kubernetes deployment. I'm try to debug the application but whenever I make a change to the image, even with a change in the tag, when I deploy the app it still uses the old image? It does update occasionally but without any rhyme or reason. This is with the imagePullPolicy set to Always.

Here is the deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: frontend
          image: myid/myapp:0.2.5
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "2Gi"
              cpu: 1
              ephemeral-storage: "2Gi"
            limits:
              memory: "2Gi"
              cpu: 1
              ephemeral-storage: "2Gi"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3838
              name: shiny-port
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: web-port
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: myregistrykey
```

I deploy it using the command

kubectl create -f deployment.yaml

Thanks

Comment: I think you made the changes and pushed to the same `tag`. 
That means any changes you make to the image won’t be picked up if you push them to the same tag. If a new pod is scheduled to the same node, the Kubelet will run the old version of the image.

Comment: Nope all new tags every time. That’s why it’s so weird

Comment: Can you describe full process how you update your deployment with new tag for the image? Because it is not clear for me, how you can deploy new pods with old tag, when your deployment.yaml has new tag. Only if you forget to update your deployment. Also, in case new image not found in docker hub (new, not ready, etc.) you will get `ErrImagePull` status during `kubectl get po`, but not pod with old image version. Also it is better to use `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml` instead of `kubectl create -f deployment.yaml` if you just want to update an image.

Answer (score 1):

*This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.*

As mentioned in comments:

- you need to check which `tag` is used - he same or different than in the previous version of the image;
- update your Deployment with actual image;
- check, if your image available in Docker hub, otherwise you will get `ErrImagePull` status during pod checking.

In case you just want to update an image, it is better to use `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml` instead of `kubectl create -f deployment.yaml`.